# Macro to add to a \ref number - broken by babel package

Tags: babel, ref

I need to add an integer to a reference number. For context, suppose I have a list of exercises where the first has `\label{exr:thisone}` (let's say it's number 6) and then I want to say something like "in exercises 6, 7 and 8...".

For that it would be handy to have a macro `\refplus` that allowed me to write

```
in exercises \ref{exr:thisone}, \refplus{exr:thisone}{1} and \refplus{exr:thisone}{2}...
```

Well, I do in fact have such a macro, shown below. And it works! ... except if I use the babel package. In the example document below, everything works as expected as long as the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` is commented out. But if I activate it, the macro breaks.

As far as I have learned, the problem is that (with babel) the `\ref{#1}` in `\setcounter{counterforrefplus}{\ref{#1}}` does not return a value, so LaTeX responds with "Missing number, treated as zero."

Any ideas? Specifically, why does babel break the macro, and how can the macro be made compatible with babel?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\newcounter{counterforrefplus}
\newcommand{\refplus}[2]{%
  \setcounter{counterforrefplus}{\ref{#1}}% copy \ref{#1} to counter
  \addtocounter{counterforrefplus}{#2}%     add #2 to counter
  \thecounterforrefplus}%                   display counter

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{one}
Value of one = \ref{one}    \\
Value of one plus 3 = \refplus{one}{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  You should have a look at the `cleveref` package, where which is most likely able to to what you want.

Comment: The main problem is that you don't know the numbers the exercises will end up with; if you add an exercise between 6 and 7, you'll need to chase for all `\refplus{one}{...}` commands and fix them by hand.

Comment: I'm surprised this ever worked.  See the refcount package.

Comment: Thank you Stefan Pinnow.

John Kormylo, I'm surprised too, since \ref{#1} is not actually a number. But yes, the refcount package helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on `\ref` to be expandable to a number. Indeed, if the reference has not yet been established, you get an error.

With `babel`, the `\ref` command is made not expandable on purpose.

You *could* fix it with `refcount`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{counterforrefplus}
\newcommand{\refplus}[2]{%
  \setcounter{counterforrefplus}{\getrefnumber{#1}}% copy \ref{#1} to counter
  \addtocounter{counterforrefplus}{#2}%     add #2 to counter
  \thecounterforrefplus}%                   display counter

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{one}
Value of one = \ref{one}    \\
Value of one plus 3 = \refplus{one}{3}
\end{document}
```

However this is not a solution. Suppose you add an exercise between 6 and 7. Then your commands

```
\refplus{exr:thisone}{1} and \refplus{exr:thisone}{2}
```

will be off by one and you'll need to fix them by hand.

Use `cleveref` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{exercise}{Ejercicio}
\crefname{exercise}{ejercicio}{ejercicios}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}\label{easy}
Easy.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{less-easy}
Less easy.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{though}
Tough.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{hey}
This is stated as an exercise, but is actually an open problem.
\end{exercise}

See \cref{easy,less-easy,hey}.

\end{document}
```

[image]